# How to display custom index using Bokeh hover tool?

Tags: scatter-plot, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh to plot the results of ~700 simulations against another set of results using a scatter plot. I'd like to use the hover tool to qualitatively determine patterns in the data by assigning a custom index that identifies the simulation parameters.

In the code below, `x` and `y` are the columns from a Pandas DataFrame which has the simulation IDs for the index. I've been able to assign this index to an array using `<DataFrameName>.index.values` but I haven't found any documentation on how to assign an index to the hover tool.

```
# Bokeh Plotting
h = 500
w = 500
default_tools = "pan, box_zoom, resize, wheel_zoom, save, reset"
custom_tools = ", hover"
fig = bp.figure(x_range=xr, y_range=yr, plot_width=w, plot_height=h, tools=default_tools+custom_tools)
fig.x(x, y, size=5, color="red", alpha=1)
bp.show(fig)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [configuring the hover tool](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hover-tool) has an example of how to do this that worked for me. Here's the code I used:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
cds = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=xdata,
        y=ydata,
        desc=sim
     )
)
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = [
        ("Index", "$index"),
        ("(2z,1z)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("ID", "@desc")
]
```